# SQL Server aggregate functions issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to show staff name, purchase date and count of transactions.

Below is my code; and I get this error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 260
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Code:

```
select
    mt.StaffName,
    mp.PurchaseDate,
    [TotalTransaction] = count(mp.PurchaseID)
from 
    MsStaff mt 
join 
    MsPurchase mp on mt.staffid = mp.staffid
where 
    mt.staffname like '%o%' 
    and count(mp.PurchaseID) > 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am understanding that the error comes in that code. It will be better if you can share one Screenshot.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego — no, screen shots are generally _not_ needed when text can convey the message accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use GBH — GROUP BY and HAVING clauses.

```
SELECT mt.StaffName,
       mp.PurchaseDate,
       [TotalTransaction] = COUNT(mp.PurchaseID)
  FROM MsStaff mt JOIN MsPurchase mp ON mt.staffid = mp.staffid
 WHERE mt.staffname LIKE '%o%'
 GROUP BY mt.StaffName, mp.PurchaseDate
HAVING COUNT(mp.PurchaseID) > 1
```

Note that `COUNT(mp.PurchaseID)` only counts the non-NULL values in the `mp.PurchaseID` column.  It is slower than `COUNT(*)` unless the optimizer can determine that there are no NULL values in `mp.PurchaseID`.

Comment: what is the COUNTY(*) for?

Comment: I left your `COUNT(mp.PurchaseID)` notation unchanged, though I suspect that using `COUNT(*)` would produce the same answer in practice. And there might be an almost unmeasurable and hence probably imperceptible difference in performance between the two (or it might be measurable but probably still imperceptible) in favour of `COUNT(*)`.